# Replace src of Image tag using css property

Tags: html, css

Is there any way by which i can replace the image mentioned in SRC attribute of image tab using any of css trick ?

```
<img src = "setting-icon.png"></img>
```

i want to replace the setting-icon.png with css property, I am able to put another image in background with background-image property of image tag but i need to hid the one mentioned in src and show what the one i mention in background-image property in css.

Yes this is weird requirement but the thing is i am doing customization in a third party application where i only have control over css, I can not modify the HTML tags.

thanks for reading through !

Comment: (2020) Using JS ``getPropertyValue("--src")`` See: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/vjfpu3a2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `content:url("image.jpg")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

In your CSS,

```
.img {
    content:url("/new/image/source.png");
}
```

If you cannot modify HTML,

```
img {
    content:url("/new/image/source.png");
}
```

In HTML,

```
<img class="img"/>
```

I have not try this yet, but I not sure if the inline attribute `src` will overweight the CSS `content`.

**Update**

It should work if you already have src for your img element. Thanks @pol

Comment: He can't modify the HTML, so I assume he can't add the `class` on the image.

Comment: change to element selector then

Comment: It worked , content url overwrites the src of img tag

Comment: This may work on Chrome, but it won't work on Firefox

Comment: Thanks Li and Ali for your time and thoughts .. :) have a great day

Comment: Let me check it in different browsers

Comment: Pol, you were right.. it does not work in Firefox and IE

Comment: It's not effective solution, if it doesn't support major browsers itself. And also the `content` property is meant to be used with `psuedo-elements`

Comment: According to this [draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#content-property) `content` can be applied to elements to replace their contents with an image. Firefox *does* support it, from 63 on, but it appears to not support replacing the content of `<img>` elements, which seems like a bug. Using `content: url()` on a `<div>`, `<p>`, or even `<b>` in FF works fine (though that doesn't help the OP).

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the html attributes values with CSS, only javascript.

But, with CSS you can "hide" the image and put a background in its place.

```css
div img {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 175px;
  padding-left: 280px;
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/6f/82/6f8200c95d588fde83d1f212f674611a.jpg");
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/a1/4e/a14e880ef245c3d159ba96ebbeb4c8c3.jpg">

<div>Changed img:</div>
<div><img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/a1/4e/a14e880ef245c3d159ba96ebbeb4c8c3.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: will try this and let you know in sometime , thanks pol for your time !

Comment: @MayurRandive can you use jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: @ Deepak Yadav : No

Answer (score 2):

Good question to learn about unnoticed *selectors* using CSS,

Additionally, You can read more about other *selectors*,

For example:

```
img: hover {}
```

and some other nice selectors ***for different range of elements***

```
:active

:after

:before

:first-child

:first-letter

:first-line

:focus

:hover

:lang

:link

:visited
```

You can even conditionally select like this:

```
img[src="setting-icon.png"] {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    content:url("/new/image/source.png");
}
```

Reference:   [W3.org - Advanced Selectors](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#Selecting_by_attribute_value)

[image: Microsoft Web Expression 4]